# AngularJS and structural/behavbiour coupling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand how does AngularJs is not violating best practices :

Looking at `<div ng-click="doSomething()">...</div>`

It has those benefits :

- Behave the same in every browser. Angular takes care of the differences for you. ( **huh ?**  jQuery does it also. ( NG uses jqLite).
- Do not operate on the global namespace. .

  **huh?** - well - Also here   the anonymous function is not polluting the global namespace:

`<div class="myDiv" >...</div>`

`$(".myDiv").on('click',function (){})`

The only benefits I(!) see  here are :

- The expressions you specify can only access functions and data that *is in the scope of the element’s controller*

example :

```
<div class="navbar" ng-controller="NavController">
…
  <li class="menu-item" ng-click="doSomething()">Something</li>
…
</div>
<div class="contentArea" ng-controller="ContentAreaController">
…
  <div ng-click="doSomething()">...</div>
…
</div>
```

Where :

```
function NavController($scope) {
 $scope.doSomething = doA;
}
function ContentAreaController($scope) {
 $scope.doSomething = doB;
}
```

And :

- Create a unit test for our app logic that doesn’t require the DOM to be present.

**Question :**

Having said that , how does `<div ng-click="doSomething()">...</div>` is considered as  very different from `<div on-click="doSomething()">...</div>` ( `or $(..).on('click'....)`) ?

Comment: It's not considered as *very* different. Can you do webapps with jQUery, without using angular? Sure. Feel free to not use angular if you don't like it.

Comment: @JBNizet Don't get me wrong . Im not here to negate NG. I just want to understand why more and more people uses it. I must be missing something that everybody sees and I'm not.

Comment: Well, it's a framework, and not just a library like jQuery. So it helps people in architecting their app in a standard way, without reinventing the wheel, without messing too much with the DOM, and with an easy way to write automated tests. I would say that where angular shines compared to the other frameworks I know is in it's UI/model binding, which is extremely easy to use and doesn't require special types of objects or collections. That and the testability, and the possibility to use custom components thanks to directives.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Here's a good enough answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21795280/1095616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between using `ng-click` vs another javascript click handler is that any event handling outside of angular scope requires calling `scope.$apply()` in order to tell angular a change was made and to run a digest for that scope.

When you use an `ng` directive for event handling, the `ng` directives will take care of running the new digest for you.

Consider these two directives that perform identical tasks:

HTML

```
<button one ng-click="doSomething()">Update</button>
<button two>Update</button>
```

JS

```
app.directive('one', function() {
  return function(scope) {
      scope.doSomething = function() {
        scope.text_1 = "New Text"
      }       
  }
});

 app.directive('two', function() {
  return function(scope, elem) {
        elem.on('click',function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){/* must tell angular we're making a change*/
            scope.text_2='New Text'
          });
        });
  }
});
```

First requires more markup, but is easier to test, second requires additional code to notify angular of changes

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iv0DnantNHGfCwTeHoer?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: R u sure it is the main difference ? What about both mixing  html tag with functionality ?

Comment: Yes exactly. If I look at the code I see onclick vs ng-click. both means the same. (mixes html+logic) I dont see how that differs ( except for the scop part which I do understand). I mean : how would you totaly convince that's it's not the same ?

Comment: angular does put logic back in markup, just have to get used to that again. `ng-class` using conditionals is an example