# Angular.js - Is there any way to get away from ng-click and other directives that resembles inline JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The title pretty much says it all. Directives that resemble inline JavaScript leave a bad taste in my mouth. Is there any way to steer clear of them altogether? Is there a better way within Angular?

Here's a quick example:

```
<div ng-click="open(argumentOne, argumentTwo, ...)"></div>
```

Comment: Could this help: javascript - using function calls in html - bad or good? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795105/

Comment: You don't have to use an inline click handler. You could create a custom directive and handle the click event within your link function.

Comment: Thanks, Radim. Pixelbits, do you know where I might find a working example of what you've described?

Comment: For ngChange, you can usually achieve the same behavior using a watch or Object.defineProperty in the model.

Comment: I'm not convinced that creating directives for every click-handler you might want to have is a good idea once an application grows but I've been wrong before. I personally think your example looks fairly good. It's declarative, it's perfectly clear what it does and I can get a good idea of what's going to happen without sifting through a bunch of other files.

Comment: Ivami, fair enough. Yours tends to be a point that continuously resurfaces with respect to the question of certain Angular directives being obtrusive.

Comment: This is the way to do it in Angular, and any other way would just be a hack.

Comment: FWIW I tried to play around with making directives for handling clicks and I was not able to come up with something that I liked. I ended up having to break my own personal rules about isolating scopes and creating things that can be unit tested in isolation. It could be that I lack knowledge about what can be done in Angular. There are perfectly fine alternatives out there when it comes to frontend frameworks. I don't want to start a holy war but I do like a lot of what Backbone does and there you'd be declaring event handlers outside the templates.

Comment: People, get serious !!! `ngClick` (and all other `ng<Event>` directives) are **not** inline JS, they are directives. What are you talking about creating directives and specifying the click handler in the link function ? That's exactly what `ngClick` is about.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : publish your handlers on the $scope

Step 2 : unit test them.

Step 3 (optional) : e2e/functional tests on the UI.

Alternative method : for complex interactions, encapsulate your code chunks into directives, and unit test them.